# Is it possible to use Bit without a bit.dev account?

Tags: bit.dev

Is it possible to set up bit as a local server, without a bit.dev account, for internal processing?

I know that you might not have the same features -- [bit's FAQ page](https://docs.bit.dev/docs/faq) says "*Unlike the Bit CLI, the bit.dev server is a proprietary tool owned by Bit. Bit.dev provides additional functionality on top of a bit server, such as component search, playground and CI for components*" but does that mean that I can work without bit.dev?

If that's possible, can you point me to documentation on doing this? How to add users, how to work?

Answer (score 4):

yes, it's possible to setup a `bare scope` which is similar to git's `bare repository`.
https://bit.dev/docs/scope/creating-scopes

Of course most features are going to be missing.
Version v15.0.0 is going to significantly improve things with features like built-in web UI for the bare scope. :)